# Notice: Undefined variable: secureRenderer in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/

Tags: magento2.3.4

hello i get this error with my module on my store magento

Notice: Undefined variable: secureRenderer in /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Webkul/VideoPlayer/view/adminhtml/templates/helper/gallery.phtml on line 38

and the code

```
        <?= $secureRenderer->renderEventListenerAsTag(
        'onclick',
        "jQuery('new-video').modal('openModal'); jQuery('#new_video_form')[0].reset();",
        'button#add_video_button'
    ) ?>
```

[image]

Comment: I think this will be the solution to your problem https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365383/magento-2-undefined-variable-securerenderer

Comment: thank you for replay @byalexes i think this post not help me my probblem is module out magento stock files and this post problem with shipping helper file this stock file in magento system but my problem with module and jequry

Comment: Based on the error that the PHP interpreter gives, you definitely have a problem with the $secureRenderer variable. It simply doesn't exist.